# How can we Group BY a column in SQL with inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I will attach a screenshot, please look at it:

[image: CLIK HERE TO VIEW PICTURE]

In this I need to get sum of the [LOCAL CURRENCY] according to each each Branch Name

```
SELECT 
    BR.BranchName [BRANCH NAME],
    PDS.ProductName [CURRENCY], 
    SUM(FCBD.Quantity) [QUANTITY],
    FCBD.BuyingRate [RATE],
    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 3), (FCBD.Quantity * FCBD.BuyingRate))) [LOCAL CURRENCY], 
    0 [TOTAL]
FROM 
    ALX_FCBuy FCB
INNER JOIN 
    ALX_FCBuyDetails  FCBD ON FCB.FCBuyID = FCBD.FCBuyID
INNER JOIN 
    ALX_Branches BR ON FCB.BranchID = BR.BranchID                   
INNER JOIN 
    ALX_Products PDS ON FCBD.ProductID = PDS.ProductID
GROUP BY 
    BR.BranchName, FCBD.ProductID, PDS.ProductName, FCBD.BuyingRate
```

Comment: post  code  please and not the image .. otherwise how we can write all the code ?

Comment: The code .. seems  syntactically corret  .. whats the problem? .. could be you don't obtain the desired result... or you have error?

Comment: In this I need to get sum of the [LOCAL CURRENCY] according to each each Branch Name,

Comment: Post the expected result also that will help understanding your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
BR.BranchName [BRANCH NAME],
PDS.ProductName [CURRENCY], 
SUM(FCBD.Quantity) [QUANTITY],
FCBD.BuyingRate [RATE],
SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 3), (FCBD.Quantity * FCBD.BuyingRate))) [LOCAL CURRENCY], 
SUM(SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 3), FCBD.Quantity * FCBD.BuyingRate))) OVER (PARTITION BY BR.BranchName)  [TOTAL]
 FROM 
ALX_FCBuy FCB
 INNER JOIN 
ALX_FCBuyDetails  FCBD ON FCB.FCBuyID = FCBD.FCBuyID
 INNER JOIN 
ALX_Branches BR ON FCB.BranchID = BR.BranchID                   
 INNER JOIN 
ALX_Products PDS ON FCBD.ProductID = PDS.ProductID
 GROUP BY 
BR.BranchName, FCBD.ProductID, PDS.ProductName, FCBD.BuyingRate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the sum for each branch, then only put that in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT BR.BranchName [BRANCH NAME],
        SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 3), FCBD.Quantity * FCBD.BuyingRate)) [LOCAL CURRENCY], 
FROM ALX_FCBuy FCB INNER JOIN 
     ALX_FCBuyDetails FCBD
     ON FCB.FCBuyID = FCBD.FCBuyID INNER JOIN 
     ALX_Branches BR
     ON FCB.BranchID = BR.BranchID INNER JOIN 
     ALX_Products PDS
     ON FCBD.ProductID = PDS.ProductID
GROUP BY BR.BranchName;
```

If you want an *additional* column in your existing result set, then the calculation would use window functions:

```
SELECT . . .
       SUM(SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 3), FCBD.Quantity * FCBD.BuyingRate))) OVER (PARTITION BY BR.BranchName) as Total
. . .
```

Comment: hello sir, i need all the columns shown in Pic , extra this column also

Comment: @swethavijayan . . . That is the second query in the answer.

Comment: It is Showing this ERROR:     Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

Comment: @swethavijayan . . . This is a strange error.  You can *definitely* do `sum(sum( . . . )) over (partition by . . . )`.  But you have to be careful, the inner `sum()` doesn't have the `over`, only the outer one.

Comment: didn't understand sir can u explain

Comment: s sir it works the brackts that u put is not completely SUM(SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 3), FCBD.Quantity * FCBD.BuyingRate))) OVER (PARTITION BY BR.BranchName)  [TOTAL]